# How to download a file from url and save the file in asset folder in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, readfile

In my flutter project, I want to download some files from a url and save particularly in a folder named data. I have added Read and Write permission in AndroidManifest.xml file. I have also tried some solutions like the below link-

[flutter - How to download asset when apps launched and used it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58652546/flutter-how-to-download-asset-when-apps-launched-and-used-it)

But none of them was effective for me. some of the solutions let me save the file in SD card but I only need to save the file in my data folder and read data from the file whenever I need.

Here's the picture where I exactly want to save my file-

[image]

So, I need a proper solution to download the file from the url and save it to this particular directory.

Comment: post your code then

Comment: I haven't any idea to code for this, I just tried the solution found in the link mentioned in my question. But I needed one example or any suggestion for the problem, that's why I posted here.

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/download_assets if you don't want to add assets at time of build try this package it download asset from server and store it in assets

Comment: Your solution let me save the downloaded folder to this directory -  /data/user/0/{package name}/app_flutter/assets/__MACOSX/._flutter.png

But I wanted to save the file inside one of my app's folder(like I posted one image in my question) and declare it to pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to save any file from url in the data folder of the application and read it.

First you need to install the path_provider and http packages.

open terminal and run scripts:

```
flutter pub add path_provider
flutter pub add http
```

Let's add the files to the beginning of the file.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' show get;
```

Now let's write the download and save code:

```
Future<bool> yourMethodName(String downloadUrl) async {
  var url = Uri.parse(downloadUrl);
  var response = await get(url);

  var documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  // yourDirectoryName or assets...
  var yourPath = "${documentDirectory.path}/yourDirectoryName";
  var filePathAndName = '$yourPath/fileName.jpg';

await Directory(yourPath).create(recursive: true);
File yourFile = File(filePathAndName);
yourFile.writeAsBytesSync(response.bodyBytes);

return true;
}
```

Call from within any function

```
callFunction()async{
 await yourMethodName('http://example.com/image.jpg'); // Or pdf,or etc.
}
```

There is a different approach for each file. If you give more detailed information, I can help you with the reading. For example I want to read picture or pdf.

If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask.