# Cache network image in mobile storage for long time using cached_network_image

Tags: flutter, dart, caching

`Is there any way to cache network image in mobile storage for long time in sharedPreference?`

I am using [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package but it saves the images only when the app is online but I want to save it in shared Preference so that i can store it for long time

Comment: Possibly you could download your images to the client, creating your own "cache." You can use an API to tell your app when images need to be downloaded and replaced. Then you just load the images from assets instead of the network. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58652546/flutter-how-to-download-asset-when-apps-launched-and-used-it

Answer (score 1):

`cached_network_image` (or better said `flutter_cache_manager`) stores the images for long time - no need for shared preferences.

But it only does so, when instructed by the cache headers. So you have to make sure your server is returning the correct `Cache-Control` headers.

If this is not possible, you can create your own `FileService` and for the `FileServiceResponse` pass a `validTill` which is far in the future.

You can check the source code of the package for the default `FileService` implementation which looks at the `Cache-Control` headers:

https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cache_manager/blob/3bd49b866d9b5e6ce09d2283f0ef97488be97e1d/flutter_cache_manager/lib/src/web/file_service.dart#L85-L106